# ffmpeg Too many bits per frame requested

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mov

I am using ffmpeg to convert videos to mp4 format. Everything works fine except with MOV format.

The command I use for everything is:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -strict experimental -sameq -s vga -aspect 1.7777 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -crf 22 -y output.mp4`

but the output I keep getting is:

```
ffmpeg version 0.9, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
built on Mar 12 2012 11:01:05 with gcc 4.4.5
configuration: --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --disable-yasm
  libavutil    51. 32. 0 / 51. 32. 0
  libavcodec   53. 42. 0 / 53. 42. 0
  libavformat  53. 24. 0 / 53. 24. 0
  libavdevice  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavfilter   2. 53. 0 /  2. 53. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x21767a0] Referenced QT chapter track not found

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 30.00 (30/1) -> 30.07 (2225/74)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2009-04-04 07:12:29
    comment         : EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY  KODAK Z1275 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA
    comment-eng     : EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY  KODAK Z1275 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA
  Duration: 00:00:17.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8100 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7968 kb/s, 30.07 fps, 30.07 tbr, 8544k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-04-04 07:12:29
      handler_name    : 
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_mulaw (ulaw / 0x77616C75), 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-04-04 07:12:29
      handler_name    : 
[buffer @ 0x2187f00] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
[scale @ 0x219c120] w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv420p -> w:640 h:480 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[libx264 @ 0x2190d20] using SAR=4/3
[libx264 @ 0x2190d20] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0x2190d20] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x2190d20] 264 - core 120 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=22.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[aac @ 0x21917e0] Too many bits per frame requested
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2009-04-04 07:12:29
    comment         : EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY  KODAK Z1275 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA
    comment-eng     : EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY  KODAK Z1275 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 30.07 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-04-04 07:12:29
      handler_name    : 
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-04-04 07:12:29
      handler_name    : 
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_mulaw -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

It seems the problem is with audio's bit per frame.
Which might be the right solution?

Answer (score 10):

The "`Too many bits per frame requested`" error is coming from the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-c:a aac`). You can use one or more of the following solutions:

## Update your `ffmpeg`

Development is very active and the native FFmpeg AAC encoder has seen many improvements; **it will now automatically clamp to the max number of bits per frame instead of failing with this error**. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to already compiled binaries which are the easiest method to get a recent `ffmpeg`.

### If you're stuck with an old, outdated, ancient `ffmpeg`:

- Increase the audio sampling rate such as by adding `-ar 44100`.
- Decrease your bitrate. Default is probably `-b:a 128k`. Try lower values until it works.
- Use `-c:a copy` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the audio, and, because MP4 doesn't support `pcm_mulaw`, use different output container format such as Matroska (`.mkv`).
- Use a different AAC encoder such as `libfdk_aac` if your `ffmpeg` supports it.

You don't need to do any of these options if you upgrade `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard can `FFmpeg` do video compression using hardware in android?

Comment: @kishorejethava I don't know what your question has to do with the answer above, but see [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware Acceleration Intro](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro); specifically the MediaCodec stuff.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm cropping video in square but It takes 9 to 10 sec of 15 sec `video` in smallest resolution (320 * 240) and when I Increase this resolution (640 * 480)  or more, cropping time also increase. my goal is how can i decrease time in high resolution video.

Comment: @kishorejethava You should ask this as a new question. This has nothing to do with `Too many bits per frame requested`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd hope ffmpeg is more clever than this, but you might try specifying the video stream for your `-s` and `-aspect` options: `-s:v` and `-aspect:v`.

Alternately, since you're not doing anything special with the audio, you could copy it explicitly with `-c:a copy`.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers but when using `-c:a copy` I get another error: `[mp4 @ 0x273d220] track 1: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container`. I tried using `-acodec libfaac -ar 48000` and it seems to work properly now.

Comment: `pcm_mulaw, 16000 Hz, 1 channels` must not be supported in MP4 container, so you must re-encode (as you've mentioned), or use must use another container such as MKV.

Comment: `-c:a copy` worked for me with a different conversion, but same error. good catch.